# Change the installation of TeX

Tags: installing, mactex, macports

I have updated my OS X to Mountain Lion, and am experiencing a problem. I have on my system two installations of `TeX`, namely `MacTeX` and `TeXLive` from macports. I am using only the first one, and the second one was installed as some dependency and I never bother to remove it.

Anyway, after the update, my system tries to use the `macport`'s installation. **How can I change it?** How can one change the default installation of `TeX`, assuming that there is more then one?

Comment: Have you tried running `FixMacTeX2012.pkg` located in `/Applications/TeX`?

Comment: MacTeX installs it in `/Applications/TeX`: the `TeX` folder in `Applications`. If you don't have it you should reinstall MacTeX.

Comment: I found it, and ran it - it didn't help. Still when calling `pdfLaTeX` it executes the one from Macports.

Comment: What is the output when you execute `which pdflatex` in terminal?

Comment: Sorry... I forgot to restart the `bash`. Seems to work just fine. Would be nice if you turn this into an answer :) THANKS!

Comment: @Dror Please, show also the output of `echo $PATH` on the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with MacTeX 2012 and/or upgrading can be fixed by running `FixMacTeX2012.pkg` which is located in `/Applications/TeX`: the `TeX` folder in `Applications`.

If this doesn't work a reinstall is in order, be sure to [verify your download](http://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html).